# Non-recursive method to count occurrences of digit in range of integers

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm working on a problem to count the number of 2s between 0 and n in decimal representation, without using a recursive solution. I found the following solution and I'm debugging it, and my question is: what is the logical meaning of `seendigits`, and statements `countof2s += digit * position * pow10_posMinus1` and `seendigits = seendigits + pow10_pos * digit`? If anyone could offer any insights, that would be great.

```
 public static int count2sI(int num) {
    int countof2s = 0, digit = 0;
    int j = num, seendigits = 0, position = 0, pow10_pos = 1;
    /* maintaining this value instead of calling pow() is an 6x perf
     * gain (48s -> 8s) pow10_posMinus1. maintaining this value
     * instead of calling Numof2s is an 2x perf gain (8s -> 4s).
     * overall > 10x speedup */
    while (j > 0) {
        digit = j % 10;
        int pow10_posMinus1 = pow10_pos / 10;
        countof2s += digit * position * pow10_posMinus1;
        /* we do this if digit <, >, or = 2
         * Digit < 2 implies there are no 2s contributed by this
         * digit.
         * Digit == 2 implies there are 2 * numof2s contributed by
         * the previous position + num of 2s contributed by the
         * presence of this 2 */
        if (digit == 2) {
            countof2s += seendigits + 1;
        }
        /* Digit > 2 implies there are digit * num of 2s by the prev.
         * position + 10^position */
        else if (digit > 2) {
            countof2s += pow10_pos;
        }
        seendigits = seendigits + pow10_pos * digit;
        pow10_pos *= 10;
        position++;
        j = j / 10;
    }
    return (countof2s);
 }
```

Comment: do you count the number of `2`'s in the decimal representation of the number from `0` to `n`?

Comment: @svs, nice catch. Yes, decimal, let me correct the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digits are processed from right to left. For the input 2468, the first iteration processes digit 8, the second 6, then 4, and finally 2.

The variable `seendigits` keeps track of the combined value of the digits that have already been processed; e.g. for the input 2468, the value during the four iterations would be 0, 8, 68 and 468. This value is used when a digit equals 2 (see below).

It is important to note that when processing a digit, e.g. 4 in the example 2468, the number of twos in the lower digits for the range 1 to 68 have already been counted. This count is used for the range 401 to 468, so what still needs to be counted is the number of twos in the lower digits for the range 1 to 400, and the number of twos in the current digit for the range 1 to 468. This algorithm does these two things seperately.

**Counting the twos in the lower digits** is done in this line:

```
countof2s += digit * position * pow10_posMinus1;
```

In the first iteration this adds 0, because there are no lower digits. In the second iteration, this adds `digit * 1 * 1`, because there is 1 lower digit, and it equals 2 once for every value of the current digit. In the third iteration, this adds `digit * 2 * 10`, because there are 2 lower digits, and they each equal 2 ten times for every value of the current digit, and so on ...

For the example input 2468, this line would add:
iteration 1: digit = 8, add: 8 * 0 * 0 = 0
iteration 2: digit = 6, add: 6 * 1 * 1 = 6
iteration 3: digit = 4, add: 4 * 2 * 10 = 80
iteration 4: digit = 2, add: 2 * 3 * 100 = 600

*e.g. the value 80 is the number of twos in the lower digits of numbers 1 to 400:

Lowest digit of x02, x12, x22, x32, ... x92

These occur 4 times: for 2 to 92, for 102 to 192, for 202 to 292 and for 302 to 392.

Second-lowest digit of x20, x21, x22, x23, ... x29

These occur 4 times: for 20 to 29, for 120 to 129, for 220 to 229 and for 320 to 329.*

**Counting the twos in the current digit** is done in one of the following lines, depending on whether the current digit is greater than or equals 2.

```
if (digit == 2) { countof2s += seendigits + 1; }
else if (digit > 2) { countof2s += pow10_pos; }
```

If the current digit is greater than 2, the number of times the digit was two while counting up from 1 depends only on the position of the digit. For position 0, this adds +1, to count the number 2; for the position 1, this adds +10, for the highest digits in the range 20 to 29; for position 2, this adds +100, for the highest digit in the range 200 to 299, and so on ...

For the example input 2468, this line would add:
iteration 1: digit = 8, add: 1
iteration 2: digit = 6, add: 10
iteration 3: digit = 4, add: 100
iteration 4: digit = 2, add: 0 (digit is not greater than 2)

If the current digit equals 2, the number of times the digit was two while counting up from 1 equals the value of the lower digits + 1.

For the example input 2468, this line would add:
iteration 1: digit = 8, add: 0
iteration 2: digit = 6, add: 0
iteration 3: digit = 4, add: 0
iteration 4: digit = 2, add: 469
This is because the current digit equals 2 in the range 2000 to 2468.

**UPDATE:**

The algorithm is easier to follow if you process the digits left to right: *(example in javascript)*

```js
function twosInRange(number) {
    var digits = Math.floor(Math.log(number) / Math.log(10));
    var count = 0;
    for (var pos = digits; pos >= 0; --pos) {     // 3, 2, 1, 0
        var unit = Math.pow(10, pos);             // 1000, 100, 10, 1
        var digit = Math.floor(number / unit);    // 2, 4, 6, 8
        number -= digit * unit;                   // 468, 68, 8, 0
        // COUNT OCCURRENCES IN LOWER DIGITS:
        count += digit * pos * (unit / 10);       // + 2*3*100, 4*2*10, 6*1*1, 8*0*0
        // COUNT OCCURRENCES IN CURRENT DIGIT:
        if (digit > 2) count += unit;             // + (1000), 100, 10, 1
        else if (digit == 2) count += number + 1; // + 469, (69), (9), (1)
    }
    return (count);                               // 600 + 80 + 6 + 100 + 10 + 1 + 469
}

document.write(twosInRange(2468));                // = 1266
```

Comment: Thanks m69, great answer and most of my questions are resolved. Confused by what you mean "because there are 2 lower digits, and they each equal 2 ten times for every value of the current digit", especially what do you mean by "equal 2 ten times for every value of the current digit"? A bit more details are appreciated. :)

Comment: That means: for every value x of the current digit (=hundreds), there are ten numbers where the lowest digit is 2 (x02, x12, x22, x32, ..., x92) and ten numbers where the second-lowest digit is 2 (x20, x21, x22, x23, ..., x29). So for every hundred numbers, there are 20 twos in the lower two digits. If the current digit is e.g. 4, that means 80 twos.

Comment: Thanks m69, could I understand in this way, for the 2nd iteration, it considers data range from 9 to 68, and for the 3rd iteration, it considers data range from 69 to 468?

Comment: Hi m69, to elaborate a bit more for my confusion, for the 2nd iteration, we consider until number 69, then it seems 3rd loop considers data from 100 (as 3rd digit count)? So, my confusion is it seems 69 to 99 are missing?

Comment: My third paragraph explains this: when processing the third digit, the twos in the third digit and the twos in the two lower digits are counted seperately. For the lower digits, the twos from 1-68 have already been counted, and this count will be used for the range 401-468, so you still need to count the twos from 1-400.

Comment: Thanks m69, for your comments, "the twos from 1-68 have already been counted, and this count will be used for the range 401-468", it is true, but values from 69 to 99 are missing?

Comment: The range 1...468 is not split 1...68 + 69...468, but 1...400 + 401...468, with the count for 1...68 used for the 401...468 range. So the range 69...99 is simply part of the 1...400 range.

Comment: I thought a bit more for your solution, not sure if it has an issue. When position is 3, you consider all numbers in range of (0, 2468) and has 4 digits. And when position is 2, you should consider all numbers in range of (0, 468) and have 3 digits. So it seems numbers from 469 to 999 are missing? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: When position is 3, all twos in the highest digit are counted for 1-2468, and all twos in the 3 lower digits are counted for 1-2000. The twos in the lower digits for 2001-2468 are counted in the next iterations.

Comment: Thanks m69, in your sense, what is the exactly data range evaluated when position is 3 in your new implementation?

Comment: My previous answer specifically addresses this question. I'm running out of ways to explain this.

Comment: let me figure out and practice myself, no worries.